# curl + sessions

Tags: unix, curl

I'm making POST requests with CURL, and I would like to output cookies made during that request... Is that possible? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I follow, but - could you use the `-c` or `--cookie-jar` option?  Use `-` to get cookies written to stdout.

Ref: [a curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: tnx, I was looking for that :) Though I don't understand how I missed it, I was reading on man... :)

Answer (score 0):

curl's  `-c` and `--cookie-jar` options will handle cookies that are created using `Set-Cookie` headers in an HTTP response.  Any cookies that are created by JavaScript on a web page will not be handled by curl (or wget, for that matter).   So if you're using the `-c` and `--cookie-jar` options and finding things aren't working, check to see whether the cookies are set by JavaScript or by HTTP headers.